# How to understand this usage of 「〜て来た」?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I found a slightly unnatural use of 「〜て来た」 in the postscript of the Gospel in colloquial Japanese.

> 当時口語の聖書はなかった。のみならず私の改訳について
>
> 聖書改訳文は元訳の文体に限り申候　口語体は威厳なく口調悪く記憶に不便に候　勅語もし口語体にて作られる時代来らばイザ知らず云々
>
> と言って来た人があった位である。
>
> （中略）
>
> そのうちに世の中の風潮も変わって来て、私の訳が出来て六年後、二十五年になって、カトリックから新約の口語訳が出た。また二十七年にキリスト新聞社から、これも新約の口語訳が出た。私は日本における口語新約聖書完訳の草分けをしようという念願は達したので、自分のものの出版の必要を感じなくなった。しかし友人の勧めによって、とにかく出版を断行することにした。そして十二、三回も稿を改めたマルコ福音書を第一分冊として、翌二十八年十二月に出版した。この時はさすがに口語訳を非常に**喜んで来た**。
>
> 「註解なしにはわからなかった処がすらすらと、生き生きと読み取れ、身に迫ってまいります」というようなのが沢山あった。これに励まされて私も改訳を急いで訂正しようと決心した。

塚本虎二訳　1993　『新約聖書　福音書』　岩波書店 　(bold emphasis added)

---

I have never seen this expression but it can be literally understood as:

> 喜ん(連体形・撥音便) + で(接続助詞) + 来(補助動詞) + た(過去)
>
> = 「口語訳が喜ばれるようになって来た」 People came to welcome Bible in colloquial terms.

Is my understanding correct? Are there any other possible interpretation?

Comment: It's quite possible that the same person who complained about the the "colloquial" translation 9 years ago praised the new colloquial translation published in year 28 (Showa?).  In such case we tend to omit the subject in the sentence to avoid the repetition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that it is an unusual expression, but I understood it to be exactly in the same form as the “言って来た” in “言って来た人があった位である”. That is, as an action taken toward the speaker. I find this interpretation especially likely because they both are used in conjunction with quotes from readers.

From スーパー大辞林:

> #### 来る
>
> ⑰ …話し手の方へ向かって動作が行われ…

- お客さんが(私に)電話をかけてきた
  *A customer gave me a phone call.*
- お客さんが(私に)怒ってきた
  *A customer got angry towards me.*
- おかしな服を着てたら友だちが笑ってきた
  *A friend laughed at me when I was wearing a strange outfit.*
- 口語訳を非常に喜んできた
  *People were very pleased (towards me) for the colloquial translation.*

Most occurrences of 喜んできた I could find online were not used in this sense, but rather in the sense of “以前から常々喜んできた”. But since your specific sentence begins with “この時は”, I think this can be ruled out.